# long int* to np_intp* platform dependent conversion

Tags: c++, numpy, 32bit-64bit, python-c-api

On my 64-bit office desktop this compiles fine:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

...

Py_Initialize();
import_array();

// Build array object
long int NUMEL=3;
PyObject *out_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &NUMEL, NPY_DOUBLE);
```

Conversely, on my 32-bit laptop this fails producing the error:

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
     PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, dims, typenum, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL)
```

Alternatively if I declare `int NUMEL=3` instead, the code will compile on 32-bit machine but not on the 64-bit one. I suspect that `npy_intp` is platform dependent. As I cannot define `NUMEL` of `npy_intp` type (as in practice it is passed by other C/C++-only routines), is there a way to conditionally define `NUMEL` depending on the platform within the C++-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npy_intp` is `typedef`'ed [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h#L182) to be:

```
typedef Py_intptr_t npy_intp;
```

And `Py_intptr_t` is defined in the Python C source in [`pyport.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Include/pyport.h#L147).  It is highly system dependent, see that source for details, but for most cases, unless you are dealing with Microsoft's Visual C being C89, you have `stdint.h` and can simply include it and use `intptr_t` as your type.  In C++ this comes as [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t), take a look also at its unsigned counterpart, [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

As a last resort, you could always replicate what Python does with something like:

```
#if sizeof(void *) <= sizeof(int)
    typedef int my_type;
#elif sizeof(void *) <= sizeof(long)
    typedef long my_type;
#else
    typedef long long my_type;
#endif
```

which will work on almost all platforms, although you may find it to not be portable to same weird corner case system.

Comment: Thanks. I ignored the existence of `stdint.h` (being mostly a self-learner). So if I got it correctly, `NUMEL` can be given of any `intN_t` type. But any function that passes `NUMEL` to `PyArray_SimpleNew` must pass it as `intptr_t`. Nevertheless this is not a problem, insofar as casting from `intN_t` to `intptr_t` is automatically performed.